# Adding 3rd level of map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> SCHEMA;

int main() {
    SCHEMA schema;

    // Schema table
    schema["liczby"]["wartosc"] = "column";
    schema["liczby"]["wartość"] = "int";
    schema["studenci"]["indeks"] = "column";
    schema["studenci"]["imie"] = "column";
    schema["studenci"]["nazwisko"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["id"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["nazwa"] = "column";
    schema["przedmioty"]["semestr"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["nazwa"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["rozmiar"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["projektor"] = "column";
    schema["sale"]["powierzchnia"] = "column";
}
```

How can I add the third level for this map?
I've tried something like this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::string>> SCHEMA;
```

...but it doesn't work. I would like to have this result:

```
schema["sale"]["powierzchnia"]["id"] = "column";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with your two levels of map.  To get three levels:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string> > > SCHEMA;
```

Or, formatting with line breaks to make the hierarchy more obvious:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, 
                 std::map<std::string, 
                          std::map<std::string, std::string> > > SCHEMA;
```

The first argument to `std::map` is the type of key, and the second argument is what the key maps to.  So, each level (except the last) maps to the next level of map.